# select all numbers that start with 04 with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have a list of cusomer numbers with up to 3 telephone numbers per customer these are not in order of home or mobile they are all mixed up.
I would like to be able to find if column B,C or D have a mobile number (start with 04) and if they do then copy that mobile number (from B,C or D) and the customer number (column A) to a new sheet.
If there is more than one mobile number I would like to copy the customer number twice.

Comment: Please provide some of your code so that SO users can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't 100% clear but I believe this is what you're asking.

You have a customer ID, and up to 3 telephone numbers, something like this.

[image]

You want to create a list of customer IDs and mobile numbers, something like this:

[image]

Here are the steps I'd use. Activate the macro recorder and carry out these steps, that should give you enough VBA to start you off if you need to automate this.

1. You only want to keep the mobile numbers prefixed 04 (green cells).
   [image]
2. In 3 adjacent columns, enter an IF statement to check how the number begins. If it's a mobile number, return the number, if not then leave blank.
    `=IF(LEFT(D22,2)="04",D22,"")` (assuming D22 contains a phone number)
   [image]
3. Select all the IF columns, copy them and paste special as values. Remove your original phone number columns.
   [image]
4. Now simply copy your customerID column and each mobile number column one above another, like this:
   [image]
5. Finally sort by mobile number to get all the blanks into one place and delete these rows.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use an advanced filter. This is an example I recently used

```
Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A3:Q" & LetzteZelle).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("T3:AJ4"), CopyToRange:=Range( _
    "A5:Q5"), Unique:=False
```

To make it work you have to copy the titles of your original table to make the criteria table. Here you write your criteria

```
=04*
```

in each column containing a phone number, but all in different rows. (Criteria in same row - AND, in different row - OR)
Now you modify the ranges of my example to fit your sheets and start this makro **from the sheet you wish your data to be copied to**